# Extracting QA Bits for Mask for Landsat Surface Reflectance?

Tags: landsat, masking, google-earth-engine

I am trying to create a mask that I can map over an image collection using the QA band from Surface Reflectance data in Google Earth Engine. Here are the indicator bits for the QA band:

- 0:unused
- 1:valid data (0=yes, 1=no)
- 2:ACCA cloud bit (1=cloudy, 0=clear)
- 3:unused
- 4:ACCA snow mask
- 5:land mask based on DEM (1=land, 0=water)
- 6:DDV (Dense Dark Vegetation)

Here is my code I keep getting the error 'getQAbits' is not defined within this scope.

```js
//filter

var sr1984 = ee.ImageCollection('LEDAPS/LT5_L1T_SR')
.filterDate('1984-06-20', '1984-08-31')
.filter(ee.Filter.or(
ee.Filter.and(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 59),         
              ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 18)),
ee.Filter.and(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 58), 
              ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 18))))

//addimage

var image = ee.Image(
  sr1984.filterBounds(region)
    .filterDate('1984-06-20', '1984-08-31')
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
    .first()
);

// helper function to extract the QA bits
function getQABits(image, start, end, newName) {
 // Compute the bits we need to extract.
 var pattern = 0;
 for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
 pattern += Math.pow(2, i);
 }
 // Return a single band image of the extracted QA bits, giving the     band a new name.
 return image.select([0], [newName])
 .bitwiseAnd(pattern)
 .rightShift(start);
}

// A function to mask out cloudy pixels.
var maskQuality = function(image) {
 // Select the QA band.
 var QA = image.select('QA');
 // Get the internal_cloud_algorithm_flag bit.
 var internalQuality = getQAbits(QA,2,4,  'internal_quality_flag');
 // Return an image masking out cloudy areas.
 return image.updateMask(internalQuality.eq(0));
}

maskQuality(image);
Map.addLayer(image);
sr1984masked = sr1984.map(maskQuality)
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got a capitalization error when you call that function. It's capital 'B'.